# Entity Framework Core add migration creates everything from scratch

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

The problem is as follows:

1. I create my initial database structure using `dotnet ef migrations add InitialStructure`.
2. I create the database using `dotnet ef database update`. Database has been created properly.
3. I add a single column in one of my entities.
4. I run `dotnet ef migrations add NewColumnMigration`. Migration has been generated but when I check the NewColumnMigration.cs file I can see that the `Up()` method tries to Create all tables from scratch instead of altering the one table with new column.
5. As a result, running `dotnet ef database update` fails because most of the tables have already been created.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm using latest ef core with .net core 2.1. Am I supposed to rewrite the whole `Up()` method and alter the table by myself?

**EDIT1:**

This is what I have inside my IDesignTimeDbContextFactory class:

```
public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Server=localhost;Database=dbname;User Id=dbuser;Password=123;").EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

        return new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
```

Comment: When you add the second migration, does your connectionstring point to a database where the initial structure exists?

Comment: I guess it's ok since it creates database properly creating initial migration and running database update. I've updated my question with code snippet from IDesignTimeDbContextFactory which I've red is required for proper migrations handling in ef core 2.1. It's still not working though.

Comment: I asked because I had a similar issue. I ran my database inside a Docker container and it spun up an empty database every time I restarted the container. EF needs access to a database with the current structure to see what changes it needs to make when you add a migration.

Answer (score 3):

Probably I reproduced your issue, the reason is:

once after you add a column and called command 'Add-Migration AddColumn', the class `ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs` will be changed, and your changes will be stored here.

but if you delete the migration code 'xxxx_AddColumn.cs', then run same command again, it will produce weird migration code, because it does not know where is new updates, compared your latest `ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs`, so you have to delete the new changes in this file before run other command.

I tried MSSQL and MYSQL, no same issue. but probably it's a bug of [PostgreSQL provider: Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL), you can post it over their project.

but make sure you are using latest versions for every components, including .NET core, and all packages.

Here is my sample output.

```
public partial class AddFirstNameLastName : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "FirstName",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "LastName",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            nullable: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "FirstName",
            table: "AspNetUsers");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "LastName",
            table: "AspNetUsers");
    }
}
```